# Why IIS aborting requests?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

For some users of an application, IIS is aborting the request to the server, including me. I type in the URL, and it just stops, doesn't even process. FireBug reports the request was aborted.

But I see successful logins to the application by other users. Any tips for debugging these types of issues? It seems very odd.

Comment: Yes, you need to debug IIS logs.. Look at the timestamp when you try and go there.. and it should log why its aborted, failed the connection. Most likely a certificate problem.. is your date/time set correctly on your machine?

Comment: Date/time - yes, that's fine.  I'll look into the certificate, but oddly enough, no errors in the log...

Comment: Use Fiddler, inspect the request and response packets.. see what is happening.. timing out? or an actual error.. If there is no error log maybe there are just too many request per second?